# Is the steering ratio of Ford C-Max constant or variable?

Tags: ford, steering-wheel, steering-ratio

I would like to know whether the [steering ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steering_ratio) is constant or rather variable on a Ford C-Max Mk1 (2003-2010).

Answer (score 1):

[Edmunds](http://www.edmunds.com/ford/c-max-hybrid/2013/road-test-specs1.html) is showing it as a **constant ratio (14.7:1)**. Steering type as:

> Electric-assist, speed-proportional, rack-and-pinion power steering

Variable ratio steering is not that common. If it had it, I'm sure it would appear all over the place.

Comment: Given that 14.7:1 is stoichiometric AFR, I wonder if this is an inside joke