# Steering ratio for European Ford Focus Mk2 (2004-2010)

Tags: ford, steering-wheel, steering-ratio

What is the steering ratio for the [European Ford Focus Mk2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Focus_(second_generation,_Europe)) that was in production between 2004-2010? I can not find it anywhere... I need it for a research project. There is somewhat relevant answer [about C-Max steering ratio](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/17867/3991) but that is on a different & newer model so I suspect the Focus may have a different ratio.

Thanks for help in advance!

**EDIT 1**: I found an article with a [2013 Focus steering ratio](http://www.edmunds.com/car-reviews/track-tests/2013-ford-focus-st-suspension-walkaround.html) and it says 14.7:1 which is the same like the above linked 2013 C-Max... however 2013 Focus is a European Mk3 and I need Mk2.

**EDIT 2**: [A sweedespeed forum post](http://forums.swedespeed.com/showthread.php?190520-Is-there-a-steering-rack-upgrade#post2096874) mentions 13.2:1 for a 2009 Ford Focus RS. In case the steering was not modified for the RS version (the post notes 14.7:1 for Focus ST which most likely is a Mk3 and equals to the 2013 values above) then it may also be valid for basic-level Focus Mk2.

Comment: I searched for a bit googling through the ford.com site and the media.ford.com site and could find the data for almost all fords, accept yours.  Weird.

Comment: Do you have the Vin for your vehicle?

Comment: @anonymous2 Not any more, but if you want to help you can use one of the following VINs: WF0PXXGCDP8L32540, WF0SXXGCDSAP57318 or WF0SXXGCDSPB51015. Thanks! (sorry I posted wrong VINs in last comment - already deleted it)

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://focus.thepaivas.com/focus/specs/index.html) states a 16.0:1 steering ratio, but this may only apply to the North American version.